# Price of a light weight aircraft that can be owned

Tags: aircraft-maintenance

I am just an aviation enthusiast and wanted to be a pilot someday..
I just wanted to be able to buy one light aircraft someday..

Can you tell me what would be the price of a light weight aircraft that can be bought?
And also the maintenance charges?
Thank you

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about buying advice and pricing.

Comment: well, it is also about maintainance info, you don't get that everywhere..can't the common man know?